# Grails hello world, Error executing bootstraps java linkage error

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails

I am trying to create a hello world grails app on my system.  I have created a fresh install of grails and ran the command `grails create-app racetrack` but when I then go to run my app I get the following error:

```
 ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.LinkageError: Class org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap violates loader constraints
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.LinkageError: Class org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap violates loader constraints
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:723)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:573)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:519)
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
        at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Class org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap violates loader constraints
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2365)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1763)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
        at grails.spring.DynamicElementReader.invokeMethod(DynamicElementReader.groovy:121)
        ... 26 more
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong or what I can do to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you have a conflicting jar in your classpath. Try removing any jars(maybe duplicate jars) that may be related to `org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap` e.g xerces, xml-api, xalan etc.

This shouldn't happen for a hello world application, but play around with it..goodluck!